# UnicodeString::Length() interferes with debugger display

Tags: debugging, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

The debugger seems to suppress viewing the contents of a UnicodeString in the Local Variable and Watch windows whenever the current function contains a UnicodeString::Length() call.

Running C++ Builder 10.3 Rio Enterprise (upgraded to 10.31 to try to solve the issue) where I have started a new project, added a button and put the following code in for the button.  This a stripped down version of a large piece of code to track down and reproduce the issue.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TFDQuery* qry = new TFDQuery(NULL);

    UnicodeString search = "SELECT *\rFROM Client\rWHERE id>0;";
    UnicodeString currLine;
    int to, len;

    qry->SQL->Clear();

    to = search.Pos("\r");
    while (to > 0) {
        currLine = search.SubString(1, to-1);

        qry->SQL->Add(currLine);

        //len = search.Length()-1;  // Offending line
        search = search.SubString(to+1, 999999);
        to = search.Pos("\r");
    }
    currLine = search;

    qry->SQL->Add(currLine);
}
```

The picture below shows two different runs of this code.  One is exactly as shown above (with one line commented out).  The other shows with the line included.

My concern is that the the debugger only shows the apparent address of the variable named "search" and if I expand it, it shows "????", not the contents of the variable as shown by the arrow.  Also note, the breakpoint is above the line that causes the debugger to switch views.  Any ideas how I can get the contents of "search" to appear if I actually calculate the length of the substring (rather than placing "999999" for its length)?

[image: Image showing debugger difference between including the length of string or not]

Comment: I was using 10.3 when I started this and one attempt at solving it was to look for any patches or upgrades.  I found the current version was available to download was 10.31, so I upgraded my system to 10.31 and the problems persists.  There is not existing tag to 10.3 (or 10.31, so I just used the generic flag for 10 figuring that it is a 10.x system).  I don't have enough credibility to add new flags.

Comment: there is an existing tag for 10.3, actually. I have updated your tags for you. And since you are using the latest version, please [file a bug report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com). The code is fine, so this is clearly a problem with the IDE/debugger

Comment: On a side note, you should use `MaxInt` instead of `999999` when calling `SubString()`. Or you can use [`System::Pos()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) or [`Strutils::PosEx()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.PosEx) instead of `UnicodeString::Pos()`, as they take a starting index as input, then you don't need `SubString()` at all. Or, simply use `SQL->Text = "..."` instead of `SQL->Add()` and let it parse the line breaks for you.

Comment: Issue submitted: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24343

Comment: On your side note, Remy, the issue was originally discovered because I was tracking down another issue and was verifying that SQL->Text = "..." worked OK (but was already working blind in the original project because I had used ::Length() elsewhere, so couldn't see the UnicodeString I was debugging).  When I created the above code to test that line in a separate project and could still not see the UnicodeString, I decided to track down this problem.  I narrowed down where the issue was coming from by separating out each step on a different line, making this quick and dirty code very verbose.

Comment: FWIW, irrelevant to the debugger problem, but your code can be simplified. Use `System::DynamicArray<UnicodeString> lines = Strutils::SplitString(search, "\r");` and you don't need `currLine`, `to`, or `len`, nor the entire loop. Just add `#include <strutils.hpp>` to make it available.

Comment: But if you do that, the dynarray does not display the individual strings either, just addresses. Hmmm... Can't check now, but what happens if you use the classic compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I can now partially answer my own question with a potential workaround.  Replacing the "search.Length()" with "wcslen(search.c_str())" seems to work, at least it does not have the side effect of displaying only addresses for UnicodeStrings in the watch list and and local variables windows.  At this point, I haven't thoroughly tested if this eventually raises some other problem.  But why should I have to do this for such a fundamental type to the language?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. It is a bug.

Comment: Yea, maybe I shouldn't have to, but once I replaced them in the real project (via #ifdef statements, so it is only done while debugging), the blinders were taken that allowed me to find a pesky typo since I could then see the values of the UnicodeStrings.  I will keep in my bag of tricks until the bug gets fixed.